# What activities trigger the realtionship between Flow state and Contemplative / Wellbeing practices?

Tags: neuroscience, motivation, well-being, linguistics, flow

I wanted to know experimental cases and studies where there are activities which make possible the Flow state, and how is it related to Happiness and Wellbeing.

Quoting the 2021 [study](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neubiorev.2020.12.002) "The neuroscience of positive emotions and affect: Implications for cultivating happiness and wellbeing" by Alexander et al. (see it at [Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0149763420306801) or at [Elsevier](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0149763420306801?token=3F4FFDEC14E2BADBFF294DAA167D856B073B69E0CB17F07C4EAEEDFD3659E4E3711A110246AFBBFA30BE9E3DAEC66B29&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20221025103803)'s websites):

> Short of living in Bhutan, actively engaging in behaviors that are associated with happiness and wellbeing may need to be actively practiced in contemporary society across the lifespan. As reviewed in section 8.1., mindfulness meditation and loving-kindness meditation have been linked with positive emotion outcomes and wellbeing, but additional research is needed to understand how “dosage,” and specific components of contemplative practices modulate positive emotions and associated neurophysiological correlates. Similarly, the positive psychology literature has developed a number of evidence-based strategies designed to increase and enhance positive emotions (Quoidbach et al., 2015), yet very little is known about how human neurophysiology might change in response to these strategies, and this remains an area for future research (Silton et al., 2020). Given that increased happiness is frequently observed in late life, future research may benefit from harnessing some of the strategies that are naturally employed by older individuals to enhance the experience of positive emotions (see section 5.2).

In addition section 8.2 explains:

> Achieving a flow state is a multifaceted process involving multiple neural systems and physiological processes implicated in reward and positive emotions, happiness, and life satisfaction. Given that flow states often occur during an activity, future research investigating flow may consider implementation of a mobile EEG and other wearable sensors to characterize the neurophysiological correlates of flow as they occur in the moment.

However, what activities really make people enter a Flow state?

There are also post related which cover other topics which are meaningful but different:

- [What is the difference between work engagement and flow?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17497/what-is-the-difference-between-work-engagement-and-flow)
- [What is the difference between flow and cannabis induced high?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/what-is-the-difference-between-flow-and-cannabis-induced-high)
- [What are the key features of dreams that trigger dream recall in the waking state?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/what-are-the-key-features-of-dreams-that-trigger-dream-recall-in-the-waking-stat)

Greetings.

Comment: Also related: [What are effective strategies for increasing concentration and motivation when doing seemingly passive activities such as reading journal articles?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/4355/7001)

Comment: Rather than just pointing out similar questions, you might want to highlight how they contribute to but differ from yours?

Comment: You may read Kant's famous CPR about his categories of *quality* related to your flow state term in modern psychology. He emphasized the degree of reality as its pure intuition target upon which to understand your question if any answer actually exists, and such schema ultimately lies in your proper management procedure or rule of your own inner sense of time with your content of interest.